# Laravel 5.1 can access the homepage but not the other web pages

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I am having a hard time fixing project

I'm using `Laravel 5.1`

here's my composer require

```
 "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
},
```

My machine is using `php 7.2`

The `home` blade of the site is working where this blade needs multiple `mysql query`

to load multiple records of `images` and `posts`

All images are working fine and records from the `database`

I might say that the database connection is good.

But when I tried to go to the different web pages. This gives me an error

`Internal Server Error`

So I checked the `xampp logs` and `laravel logs` but no current error shown at this time.

This is the homepage *Where you can see the posts are working fine*

[image]

and this is what I get from all the pages

[image]

and here's my vhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:0804>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/labelin.us"
    ServerName localhost
 </VirtualHost>
Listen 0804
```

Note *The reason why it doesn't contain `/public` on the `vhost` because the system moved the `index.php` from `/public` to `<root-folder>` also the .htaccess is located on `<root-folder>`*

Is there anything I need to do just to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice there's a rewrite rule for the `project url`

I'm accessing the project using `localhost:0804` only

where it should be accessing using

`localhost/labelin.us`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /labelin.us
```